# question about infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying infinite products appearing in complex analysis these days. There are lots of
theorems regarding it, for example, for $0<u_n <1,  \prod (1-u_n) > 0$, iff $\Sigma u_n < \infty $.

I come up with a following question which No elementary book say about it..

within above condition, $\prod u_n =1  $ is impossible, but i thought intuitively that by approaching$ u_n$ rapidly to 1, it is possible to get a value of infinite product is larger than 1-$\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$
(of course our$ u_n $can depend on $\epsilon$)
if anyone know about theorem regrading it or can prove about this? thanks.

Comment: If $u_n \to 1$, using the theorem you stated, the infinite product will not converge. Another thing, why is $\prod u_n =1$ impossible ?

Comment: @Teddy since infinite product is equal or less than u1<1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $0 < u_j < 1$, 
$$ \prod_{j=1}^\infty u_j = \exp\left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \ln(u_j) \right)$$
So you want $$\ln(1-\epsilon) < \sum_{j=1}^\infty \ln(u_j)$$
Can you think an infinite sum of negative terms that is greater than $\ln(1-\epsilon)$?

Comment: I can think of some geometric series ln(1/u_j) bounded by constant ln(1/(1-e))